# How do I create an object referencing an instantiated class object inside a method that didn't pass the object as an argument?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

```
synchronized void drop(Board board) {
    int[][] a = getArray();
    int[][] b = board.getArray();

    //I don't have currentObject here... what do I need to write?                
    if (Board.goDown(currentX, currentY, b, a, board, currentObject)) {
        currentY++;
        updateXY();
    }
}
```

The method call is `currentObject.drop(board)`, but we can't pass in `currentObject` as a variable.

Is there any easy way of doing this or I just have to rewrite the entire code?

Comment: Is this a method of 'currentObject'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

"this" is a reference to the current object.

Comment: So basically: if(Board.goDown(currentX, currentY, b, a, board, this))?

Comment: can you update your question? i don't see goDown method in your question